# Prevent returned reference from being copied

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some class which manages some resources. You get get a reference to one of those resources from this managing class. Resources are heavy-weight objects, so you normally don't want to copy them. In my case, a base-class for resources is no solution, because my 'resource-manager' is a template class which should work with already defined resource classes of other people. I made some simple example to show my problem:

```
#include <iostream>

// copyable class
class Copyable {
public:
  Copyable() = default;
  Copyable(const Copyable&) {
      std::cout << "Copyconstructor called" << std::endl;
  }

  Copyable& operator=(const Copyable&) {
      std::cout << "assignment operator called" << std::endl;
      return *this;
  }
};

// non copyable class
class NonCopyable {
public:
  NonCopyable() = default;
private:
  NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
  NonCopyable& operator=(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
};

// some class that can return a reference
template <typename T>
class SomeHolder {
private:
    T some_member;
public:    
    T& getReference() {
        return some_member;
    }
};

int main() {
    SomeHolder<Copyable> holder_1;
    auto copyable_1 = holder_1.getReference();    
    auto &copyable_2 = holder_1.getReference();

    SomeHolder<NonCopyable> holder_2;
    //auto noncopyable_1 = holder_2.getReference(); // line 39
    auto &noncopyable_2 = holder_2.getReference();  // line 40
}
```

The class SomeHolder returns a reference on the owned object. As you see in line 39, this reference gets copied. Normal way to get the reference is done in line 40. But if you miss the & you get a copy, which you normally don't want. If you uncomment line 39, you get an error because the resource isn't copyable in this case.
Like i said before, wanting all resources to be not copyable isn't a solution in my case. Do you have ideas to other design decisions? I write this class to hold resources for games. I am writing a small library for recurring tasks. So i don't know if your framework works with copyable textures and sounds. Maybe there is no great solution for my problem, but if you have design suggestions, let me know.

Comment: The lines aren't numbers. It's not clear which lines are 39 and 40.

Comment: If you want to store reference: use `auto&`, if you don't: use `auto`. What is the problem with such approach?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It sounds to me like OP wants the compiler to complain if anyone tries to make a copy of the returned object.

Comment: It feels bad for us to have to copy the code to an IDE to get line number. Consider having a comment in the code specify line numbers.

Comment: you can use something like `HANDLE` or `shared_ptr` which is itself copyable, but share the same resource.

Comment: Isn't it the caller's fault to copy values unnecessarily? ...

Comment: @François Andrieux sorry i will add the corresponsing line numbers.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius yeah, that is the way. But making a copy is expensive in this case. And the API would be much more robust if the API would prevent the caller from wrong usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot prevent other code from copying objects that are copyable. So, if you want other code to not be able to copy copyable objects that you hold, then you must not return a reference to them.

Instead, you could return a wrapper object, that delegates its functionality to an instance of the copyable class whose reference is held privately within the wrapper:

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
    T& t;
public:
    Wrapper(T& t) : t(t) {}
    T* operator->() { return &t; }
};

Wrapper<T> SomeHolder<T>::getSomeMember() {
    return {some_member};
}
```

Since direct member access operator cannot be overloaded, you will need to change the calling code to use the indirect member access instead.

Comment: That is a good solution. At this point, resources are stored as unique_ptrs, so maybe i could just return a const unique_ptr as resolt. Or just plain constant pointers, but that would be that good. I will check your solution in code :) Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I also suggest to use a smart pointer, but I prefer to not use reference members. That way client can keep handles.

```
template<typename T>
struct ViewPtr {
  ViewPtr() = delete;
  ViewPtr(T* tp) : tp(tp) {}
  T* operator->() { return tp; }
  const T* operator->() const { return tp; }
  private:
  T* tp;
};
```

Usage:

```
template <typename T>
class SomeHolder {
private:
  T some_member;
public:
  ViewPtr<T> getReference() {
    return &some_member;
  }
};
```

This `Viewtr` also opts to "propagate const". That is: if you have a const view object (or if it's a member, and you are in a const method) you get a const interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your objects copyable there will definitely be no way for your to prevent them from copying it....

If you return a reference to a copyable object, you can't prevent developers using your class from copying them at some point. If they use `auto&`, the object won't be copied, but if they use ̀`auto`, the object will be copied....and even if they used `auto&` when they called your `getReference()` function, you can't prevent them from doing a later copy (when they will call a function or assigning a new variable).

An alternative, as commented by "apple apple", is to return a `shared_ptr`. Then your ressource manager stores shared pointers to ressources and gives access to them. Then, the caller may use many instances of the `shared_ptr`, all pointing to the same ressource which is not copied in the end. If he uses `auto` he gets a copy of the `shared_ptr`, if he uses `auto&` he gets a reference to `shared_ptr`, but, in both case they point to the same ressource which were not copied.

If the caller really wants to do a copy, he will find a way to do it by using `shared_ptr::get()` to access the copyable object.

Comment: I don't like to take a shares_ptr. I store the objects covered in unique_ptrs, so theoretically i could return a constant reference on to the unique_ptr. The best idea i heard was that i can return the object in a wrapper class. If someone wants to copy the object and he knows why, there is no problem. But it would be bad API design if you accidentally copy a heavy weight class by forgetting one sign. So even if shared_ptrs would be a solution, they would change the whole ownership model of my code and that is nothing i want. But thanks for your input.